# Line by line file operation in Android

Tags: android, file-io, line, filewriter

I am trying to do what `FileWriter.println()` and `BufferedReader.readLine()` do in Android, but in android they only allow writing it into the sdcard using those method.

I need to write some integer values into the file and then read it line by line at a later time. Some of the file operation methods I found require the length of the data read to be specified, which is not possible.

Can anyone point me to the right method? Preferably with an example of the usage...

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write to the SD card by using this path, "\sdcard\file_name"

and read it this way,

```
 InputStream instream = null;

    as

  InputStream instream = openFileInput("/sdcard/filename");

    // if file the available for reading
    if (instream != null) {
      // prepare the file for reading
      InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
      BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);

      String line;

      // read every line of the file into the line-variable, on line at the time
      try {
        while (( line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
           Log.i(TAG, "line = "+line);
          }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

    // close the file again
    try {
        instream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: yes, but i need to write it to the application's file system, not the external storage.